# Entity Framework Core Create Unique Index on DateTime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
[Table("hProducaoRegistos", Schema = "Robotics")]
public class ProducaoRegisto
{
    public ProducaoRegisto()
    {
        DataCriacao = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Criado Por")]
    public int Operador { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Criado Em")]

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }                
    public int CelulaId { get; set; }
    public Celula Celula { get; set; }
    public int TurnoId { get; set; }
    public Turno Turno { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CheckListRegisto> CheckListRegistos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProcessoRegisto> ProcessoRegistos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DefeitoRegisto> DefeitoRegistos { get; set; } 
}
```

I want to have only a record unique by day, how can I do this using `EF7`? The objective is to make the user create a record only once per day until midnight of next day.

Comment: What do you mean by "day number"?

Comment: well I mean, the user should be able to create a new record only once per day

Comment: Code or Db first? You should be checking it with logic regardless, but also forcing it at the database level as a precaution

Comment: Code, usually i rather just create unique index and put it inside try catch to get the DbConcurrecy exception

Comment: maybe you want to use the `Date` type in your DB so it doesn't include the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about filtering by the 'day number', but if you want a Date column with a unique constraint:

With the fluent API

```
builder.HasIndex(e => e.CreatedDate)
       .IsUnique();
builder.Property(e => e.CreatedDate)
       .HasColumnType("Date");
```

With data annotations

```
[Index(IsUnique=true)]
[Column(TypeName="Date")]
public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't. You would have to change your table column type.

Comment: Yes it does, as long as the DateTimes are stored without time part. You'll have to enforce that in your business/DAL logic.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go through this approach, i created an additional column just for the date without time and the index with 3 properties worked like a charm. Records are now unique per day

Answer (score 0):

You could make an int representing the day and using this as the primary key.
The DateTime class has a Day property that will get you the day represented as an int.

Comment: The `Day` property of DateTime returns the day of the month, this wouldn't work across months.

Instead of using the `Day` property, you could calculate an int that would be how many days have passed since a base day.

Answer (score 0):

1. use timestamp  or
2. use default identity beside the date column and use linq to select specific day as you want

Comment: Timestamp, despite its name, has nothing to do with date and time.

Comment: He convert from and to it as this link shows https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/865/how-to-convert-an-unixtime-to-datetime-class-and-viceversa-in-c-sharp